# How to not move the contents in QScrollArea even on scroll

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have a scroll area in which, a widget resides, say scrollWidget. I have different images to be loaded on the scrollWidget, based on the scrollValue. Basically, on scrolling, the scroll bar should scroll, but the widget inside scrollArea shouldn't move. Based on the new scroll value, I will update the image in scrollWidget.

Checked in the source code and found that

```
void QScrollArea::scrollContentsBy(int, int)
```

is responsible for moving the widget.

So, tried to overrode the function and in the overridden function, I am just returning, doing nothing.

```
//overriden function
    void scrollContentsBy(int dx, int dy)
    {
       return;
    }
```

And the overridden function is getting called on scrollValueChanged. Even then the scrollWidget is scrolling somehow.

Is there someone else, who moves the scrollWidget inside the scrollArea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a widget with own `QScrollBar`, not a `QScrollArea`. Just place a `QScrollBar` on your widget and control it manually. Maybe it will be good to implement `QAbstractScrollArea` abstract class which can help to handle scrolls (but may cause other troubles, as often happens with Qt subframeworks...).